# HtmlWebpakPlugin generating bundled asset url with leading double slash

Tags: url, webpack, bundle, html-webpack-plugin

Somehow HtmlWebpack plugin is generating an url with leading double slashes

```html
<script defer src="//js/app.6f290bd2820c4c9e.bundle.js"></script>
```

That make the resource not being downloaded from the browser

[image]

Here is my webpack configuration

```js
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, './resources/html/index.html'),
        filename: 'index.html',
        inject: 'body',
    }),
],
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].bundle.js',
    clean: true,
}
```

I just need to have the url being generated with a single leading slash to work properly, better if without setting any base url so the code still work for both staging and production compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `publicPath` in order to override the default settings that add a `/` to any not empty string.

```
 output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].bundle.js',
    clean: true,
    publicPath: ''
}
```

with this configuration the output will be:

`<script defer src="/js/app.6f290bd2820c4c9e.bundle.js"></script>`

with a single `/` in the url.
This is because of that:

```js
let publicPath = typeof compilation.options.output.publicPath !== 'undefined' 
   // If a hard coded public path exists use it 
   ? compilation.mainTemplate.getPublicPath({hash: compilationHash}) 
   // If no public path was set get a relative url path 
   : path.relative(path.resolve(compilation.options.output.path, path.dirname(self.childCompilationOutputName)), compilation.options.output.path) 
     .split(path.sep).join('/'); 
  
 if (publicPath.length && publicPath.substr(-1, 1) !== '/') { 
   publicPath += '/'; 
 }
```

Ref:
https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/8440e4e3af94ae5dced4901a13001c0628b9af87/index.js#L411-L420